# Установка Openfire на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xmpp

Думаю о установке XMPP-сервера. [Почитал](http://jabberworld.info/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_Jabber-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) и выбрал Openfire. Однако в различных руководствах, которые я нашёл в сети, при установке Openfire описываются многие дополнительные вещи, назначение которых мне не совсем понятно.

К примеру [здесь](http://ru.man.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_OpenFire_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Ubuntu_14.04) предлагают ещё ставить mysql и php. [Здесь](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=223100.0) ставят ещё и Апач. И почему-то везде предлагают ставить оракловскую (закрытую) Яву из каких-то доп. репозиториев.

**1)** Нельзя ли использовать обычную Яву? Ту, которая распространяется под свободной лицензией и не содержит всякие малополезные рядовым ламерам суперкрутые вещи от Оракл.

**2)** Каков минимальный набор программ, который необходимо ставить на свежую Ubuntu 14.04 перед командой `dpkg openfire.deb`?

Comment: Могу сказать про второй пункт. Начни ставить, а потом посмотри на что менеджер будет ругаться. И доставляй через `aptitude`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Каков минимальный набор программ, который необходимо ставить на свежую Ubuntu 14.04 перед командой dpkg openfire.deb?

1. вы можете посмотреть зависимости, указанные внутри файла с пакетом:

   ```
   $ dpkg-deb -f openfire_4.0.2_all.deb depends pre-depends
   Pre-Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless | openjdk-7-jre | oracle-java7-jre
   ```

   символ `|` означает в данном случае условие «или».
2. а можете попробовать установить пакет из файла и получить фактически ту же информацию, но только уже в виде ошибки:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg -i openfire_4.0.2_all.deb
   Selecting previously unselected package openfire.
   dpkg: regarding /tmp/openfire_4.0.2_all.deb containing openfire, pre-dependency problem:
    openfire pre-depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless | openjdk-7-jre | oracle-java7-jre
     openjdk-7-jre-headless is not installed.
     openjdk-7-jre is not installed.
     oracle-java7-jre is not installed.

   dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/openfire_4.0.2_all.deb (--install):
    pre-dependency problem - not installing openfire
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    /tmp/openfire_4.0.2_all.deb
   ```

---

> Нельзя ли использовать обычную Яву? Ту, которая распространяется под свободной лицензией и не содержит всякие малополезные рядовым ламерам суперкрутые вещи от Оракл.

судя по приведённой выше информации и по [инструкции на сайте digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-openfire-xmpp-server-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps) — да, ведь *openjdk* — это именно свободная реализация *java development kit*.

Comment: Крутяк, про то как зависимости смотреть вообще полезно! Надо ещё поискать просмотр зависимостей для apt-get.

Comment: @hunter, `apt-cache depends имя-пакета`